# why report the error " undefined reference to `add2" when I used cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

The directory is follow:
-inlcude
Test.h
-lib
libmytest.so
-src
test.go

The test.go code is follow:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS : -I ../include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L ../lib -lmytest
#include "Test.h"
*/
import "C"
func main() {
    C.add2(10, 10)
}
```

When I use `go build test.go`, the console report that: # command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-build168903458/command-line-arguments/_obj/test.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_9efddd4c1a4b_Cfunc_add2':
rocketmq-bridge/src/cgo-gcc-prolog:42: undefined reference to`add2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

Do not add space after `CFLAGS`, and try without specifying the filename when building `cgo`, i.e.

```
go build
```

Optionally, add `-x` to the build options, then observe whether the compiler correctly add the corresponding files (INCLUDE and LIB) to its option, i.e.

```
go build -x
```